# iOS6 date formatting differences

Tags: ios

I came across weird problem

I got a string date: 2012-12-09T20:15:00+1:00

[image]

I use this simple date formatter:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'kk:mm:sszzz"];
visitDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:stringDate];
```

I get the date on iOS6 but nil on iOS5. What would be the pattern what would work on both systems. Or at least what would be pattern that would work at iOS5?

Comment: Uh, maybe you should supply a format string?  (And the "+1:00" won't parse with earlier formatters -- you have to remove the ":".)

Comment: Also, I think you need `ZZZ`, not `zzz`, even after you remove the colon. The former gives you the `+0100`, the latter gives you a three letter code for that timezone, e.g. `CET`.

Comment: See the list of "Fixed formats" links [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1).  The "ZZZZZ" format for the timezone with the colon is only iOS 6.

Comment: could anybody provide with proper pattern? I'm geting confused, do I have to remove all the colons or just those in the timezone?